# highlight duplicates on same row Excel

Tags: excel

I tried searching this but couldn't find quite what I was looking for. I'd like to highlight duplicates in an Excel Sheet but ONLY within the same row (not within same column or different columns).

My data looks something like this:

```
    DOG_ID    SIRE_ID    DAM_ID
1    1234      4567       7890
2    1546      3454       3459
3    1349      1243       1203
4    1934      1934       1928
5    1935      1349       1935
6    4567      1349       1546
```

So for my data, I would want 1934 highlighted in row 4 and 1935 highlighted in row 5, but nothing else should be highlighted. I know I'll need to use a conditional highlighting rule, but haven't quite found which one works yet.

Comment: take this solution and just replace the condition at point (4) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: Use COUNTIF in your conditional formatting (explained in the link given above).

Comment: Is there something I can use to apply to the whole sheet? I don't want to have to do each row individually. There are 12291 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Conditional Formatting for Duplicates on a Row by Row basis.

The trick is getting the absolute & relative addressing references correct.

1. Select the range of cells (rows and columns), starting from the Top Left Cell.
2. **`Home`** tab, **`Conditional Formatting`**, **`New Rule`**, **`Use Formula to determine...`**
3. Select **`Format`**, choose the desired conditional formatting. Click **`OK`**
4. Edit **`Format Values where this formula is true:`** to **`=COUNTIF($B2:$E2,B2)>1`**

   - **`$B2:$E2`** is the row containing the Top Left cell of the selection.
     *The row numbers use Relative Address Notation and the Columns use Absolute Address Notation.**
   - **`B2`** is the Top Left cell (first cell selected in range). *Relative Address Notation*

**N.B.** Text values in the range containing `*` or `?` will invoke `countif` pattern matching. Pattern matches will also be marked as duplicates.

The Format Painter can be used to extend this Conditional Formatting.

*For Column Duplicate Conditional Formatting, reverse the Relative/Absolute Address Notation in the `Countif` Column Range.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, Row As Long, Times As Long, Column As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find last row column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Find last column row 1 (with titles)
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Loop rows
        For Row = 2 To LastRow
            'Loop columns
            For Column = 2 To LastColumn
                'Loop values
                str = .Cells(Row, Column).Value
                'Set range for each row
                Set rng = .Range(Cells(Row, 2), Cells(Row, LastColumn))
                'How many times value appears in row
                Times = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, str)
                'if appears more than one times
                If Times > 1 Then
                    .Range(Cells(Row, 2), Cells(Row, LastColumn)).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If

            Next Column

        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```